# Uncaught TypeError: WebSocketClient is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, websocket, browserify

I have exported websocket using browserify ,

```
 browserify -r websocket > bundle.js
```

Then I try to run following code in my browser

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
var client = new WebSocketClient();
```

But I am getting following error in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: WebSocketClient is not a constructor
```

Can some one guide me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The websocket library uses API's that aren't available in the browser. That's why you get the _TypeError_. Browserify is a cool tool but it has it's limits. You'll have to find a different workaround. If you can elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocketClient is not supposesd to be used in a browser. There's a related issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/issues/276#:%7E:text=Guys%2C%20in%20browser,in%20the%20browser.).

Instead you should use W3CWebSocket:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;
var client = new W3CWebSocket("ws://type_ws_server_address_here");
```

Read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)